# Select field from table with @Query using Spring Boot JPARepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Is it possible to select one or more fields from a table and map it into the entity?

Currently trying

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepo extends JpaRepository<Role, Long>{  
    @Query("SELECT r.roleId, r.name FROM role r")  
    List<Role> getAllRoleNames();
}
```

I only want those 2 values and the rest of the fields can be `null` to make it more efficient. The error I get right now is

```
ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type 
[@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query demo.model.Role] for value '{1, Java Dev}'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: 
No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type 
[@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query demo.model.Role]] with root cause
```

So how can I make the conversion happen when I can't just say `object.Id = role.roleId` (`object.Id` would be that `1`).

Comment: Does [Customizing the Result With Class Constructors](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-queries-custom-result-with-aggregation-functions#solution_constructor) work for you? You can use a custom DTO as a result class

Answer (score 1):

WIth Spring Data you can use projections to accomplish this.

```
@Entity
public class ExampleEntity {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    @OneToOne
    private Person person;

    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

.

```
public interface ExampleProjection {
    String getName(); // This must be exactly the same as your entity
}
```

Now you can use ExampleProjection in your Repository, even though the repository references the ExampleEntity and not the Projection.

```
public interface ExampleRepository extends Repository<ExampleEntity, Long> {
    List<ExampleProjection> findBy();
}
```

More information here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Comment: I think it works? But the fields are all `null` which probably means my query is incorrect, but I wouldn't know how to make the proper query since I just stole it from Postgresql's pgAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, you can use a custom entity as below :

NewRole.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class NewRole implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private Long id;
private String name;

}
```

RoleRepo.java

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepo extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {  

@Query("SELECT new NewRole(r.id, r.name) FROM role r")  
List<NewRole> getAllRoleNames();

}
```

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the query up so that the fields I needed would be filled, and the other ones would be null, by adding a new constructor.

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepo extends JpaRepository<Role, Long>{  
    @Query("SELECT new demo.model.Role(r.roleId, r.name) FROM role r")  
    List<Role> getAllRoleNames();
}



@AllArgsConstructor //all arg constructor
@Data
@Entity(name = "role")
public class Role {
    public Role(Long roleId, String name) { //half arg constructor
        this.roleId = roleId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    private Long roleId;

    private String name;

    // more fields, getters, and setters
}
```